# Is it possible to pipe the result of one thread into another thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to use the result(return value) of one thread in another thread.

Example:

```
def foo():
  return "foo"
def bar():
  return "bar"

thread_foo = threading.Thread(target = foo)
thread_bar = threading.Thread(target = bar)

thread_foo.start()
thread_bar.start()
```

What I want to do is use the output of the function `foo` and use it in the function `bar`.

I read the docs but unfortunately did not find something useful.

Comment: You could use a Queue to pass data between threads https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html if you use multiprocessing you could use a Pipe instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe

Comment: I fixed s typo in subject, and fixed two syntax errors in your code.  Please at least try run your program before you ask for help.  A thread share memory, so any variable accessible by both threads can be used to exchange data.  You use a queue to manage concurrent access.

Comment: if you need result from one thread in another thread - so one thread has to wait for other thread - then threads may not have sense and simpler will be `bar(foo())`. Eventually run first function normally `result = foo()` and later `Thread(target=bar, args=(result,)`. OR create function `def other(): bar(foo())` and this runs in `Thread(target=other)`

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple example using one thread, but you could easily add more:

```py
    import Queue
    from threading import Thread
    
    def foo(bar):
        print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
        return 'foo'
    
    foo_q= Queue.Queue()
    
    t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(foo(arg1)), args=(foo_q, 'world!'))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    result = foo_q.get()
    print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an input queue for passing arguments and an output queue for getting the results is one way. In the following example, thread `squarer` is a thread that squares its input argument and "returns" the result. `bar` is another thread that uses `squarer` but could just as easily be the main thread:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

in_q = Queue()
out_q = Queue()


def squarer():
    while True:
        x = in_q.get()
        if x is None: # signal to terminate
            return
        out_q.put(x**2) # put answer

def bar():
    for x in (range(10)):
        in_q.put(x)
        result = out_q.get()
        print(f'{x}**2 = {result}')

t1 = Thread(target=squarer)
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=bar)
t2.start()
t2.join()
in_q.put(None) # signal thread to terminate
t1.join()
```

Prints:

```
0**2 = 0
1**2 = 1
2**2 = 4
3**2 = 9
4**2 = 16
5**2 = 25
6**2 = 36
7**2 = 49
8**2 = 64
9**2 = 81
```